# In proof of Schur's lemma how does having same eigenvalue leads to invariant subspace?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

(Schur’s Lemma).Let D be an irrep of G over V. Then if there exists a matrix H such that for all g∈G  [H, D(g)] = 0 =⇒H=λ·I, where λ∈C

Proof. Let v∈V be an eigenvector of H with eigenvalue λ,then if H commutes with D(g) then H(D(g)v)=D(g)Hv=λ·(D(g)v).This tells us that D(g)v is also an eigenvector of H with the same eigenvalue. This is true for all g and so we conclude that the eigenspace V_λ is an invariant subspace of D (otherwise we would get a different eigenvalue with H). But D is an irrep so it has no non-trivial invariant subspaces, and because the eigenspace is not empty we are forced to conclude thatV_λ=V, so every element in V is an eigenvector of H with eigenvalue λ. This is just the statement thatH=λ·I

can someone explain the statement starting from "we conclude"! why invariant subspace of D?? and why having the same eigenvalue matters in case of invariant subspace!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Notice that people will almost certainly pay more attention to your posts when you format them properly using mathjax.

Comment: I'd say that the proof at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma#Statement_and_Proof_of_the_Lemma is more explicit and easier to understand.

Comment: I am a physics student so that proof is a bit more troubling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we fix this $\lambda$ then we can look at the set of all vectors $v$ such that $Hv = \lambda v$.  This is called the $\lambda$ eigenspace of $H$ and in particular its easy to verify that it forms a subspace.

Now what's going on in this proof is first they show by calculation that since $H$ commutes with the elements of $G$ that if $v$ is in the $\lambda$ eigenspace of $H$ then so is $g \cdot v$ for any $g$ in $G$.

This means that the $\lambda$ eigenspace of $H$ is a $G$-invariant subspace, which since $V$ is irreducible means it must be all of $V$.  But then if every vector in $v$ just gets scaled by $\lambda$ by $H$ that implies $H$ was a scalar matrix to begin with.